# How does chemical shift assignment from NMR spectroscopy is translated to three dimensional structure of protein?

Tags: biochemistry, proteins, protein-structure

I am currently involved in determination of protein structure using NMR spectroscopy. As part of structure determination I have finished the chemical shift assignment. The chemical shift information is submitted to specialized software/servers for structure determination.

My specific question is "**how is the structure of a protein is determined using chemical shifts**"? How do the servers translate the chemical shift information to determine fully fledged 3D structure of protein?

Answer (score 0):

The *chemical shift* can be used to determine *secondary* structure, i.e. if a certain residue is part of a helix or a strand.

You’re talking about structure determination, so I assume you’re interested in obtaining the three dimensional or *tertiary* structure. For this, you will have to use proton-proton distances as restraints in structure calculations, not chemical shifts.